# How to implement closed control loop control for a 4 switch buck boost converter?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, matlab

How to can I design a controller for 4 switch buck boost converter ? I used a PID Controller as shown in the image. .[image]

I haven't yet found out the right values for the PID controller gain. I want it to be bidirectional So I don't think its going to work.

Comment: Before attempting to compensate anything, you need the control-to-output transfer function of your converter. From these data (magnitude-phase response versus frequency), you will derive a control strategy based on poles-zeroes placement that you can easily converter into PID coefficients (see this [APEC seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf)). To obtain the transfer function of the power stage, use analytical analysis or SIMPLIS which can do the job quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Do this (assuming that your loop is controllable and not unstable) :

Open loop method to tune a PID controller

- Freeze the PID output
- Make a step change on the PID output (MV) in order of 3-10%. Step should be sufficiently big to see its effect on the controlled process variable (PV)
- Log response of MV and PV and fit the model parameters of a First Order Time Delay model to this response.
- Use model based tuning method, such as Table 1 for single PID loops

[image]
Source: https://www.pid-tuner.com/pid-control/